# How make Dictionary with lambda functions, with different numbers of parameters

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, delegates

How make Dictionary with lambda functions, that Func<> contains different numbers of parameters?

```
Dictionary<string, Func<T, double>> operationsList 
  = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, double>>();
```

It mast be so?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more concrete, that's not really clear.

Comment: Supposing you did, how would you use such a dictionary?

Comment: You can't.  Dictionaries only store one type.  If you want to store heterogenous objects, you have to use `Object` or `dynamic`, and then cast to the type you want.

Comment: You can make your Dictionary<string,Delegate> ,but I'm not sure this iw what you want

Comment: Please provide a code example showing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your dictionary type `Delegate`, but I'm pretty sure that calling `Func<>` stored this way will be a pain:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Delegate>();
dict.Add(1, (Func<int, int>)((int x) => x * 10));
dict.Add(2, (Func<int>)(() => 10));
```

Calling:

```
var result1 = dict[1].DynamicInvoke(10);
var result2 = dict[2].DynamicInvoke();
```