# Storing a list of Actions with parameters and later executing them

Tags: c#, .net, action

I have an enum, of Actions, I want to run:

```
public enum theActions
{
    action1,
    action2
}
```

I want to store them, in a Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<theActions, Action> _theActions { get; }

_theActions = new Dictionary<theActions, Action>
{
    [theActions.action1] = () => action1Func()
};
```

I'd have my functions, for each action(s):

```
public void action1Func(int inParam)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

Later, I'd need to call one of the functions:

```
public void execAction(int inVar, Action action) 
{ 
    //inVar isn't the parameter I want to pass to the action. It's used, for something else.
    action(); 
}

execAction(1, _theActions[theActions.action1]);
```

I'm not sure, how to change my code to make the Action take parameters everywhere and what if I need one action which doesn't need a parameter?  Do I have to add a dummy parameter, in that function?

**I got this, so far:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public enum theActions
        {
            action1,
            action2
        }

        public Dictionary<theActions, Action<int>> _theActions { get; }

        public void execAction(int inVar, Action<int> action)
        {
            //inVar isn't the parameter I want to pass to the action. It's used, for something else.
//            action();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _theActions = new Dictionary<theActions, Action<int>>
            {
                [theActions.action1] = (Action<int>)((int x) => action1Func(x))
            };

        }

        public void action1Func(int inParam)
        {
            //do whatever
            MessageBox.Show($"Hello ... inParam : {inParam}");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This works manually
            _theActions[theActions.action1].Invoke(12);

            //But, I want the execAction to work
            //execAction(1, _theActions[theActions.action1]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works manually calling it.  I just need help getting into execAction() and running it.  So, close.

Comment: I think you are confused how to implement this because you are confused about what you actually want to do. If you don't know which parameters a method will need, how will you build a way to provide them? If your executor method always takes for example an int, what would you even do if the action takes two strings?

Comment: In this case, it'd always be a single int parameter.

Comment: Then make your action an `Action<int>`.

Comment: I add <int> after all the Action statements.  I get errors.

Comment: Do you have the parameters info at the time of initialization `[theActions.action1] = () => action1Func()` or will you have those parameters at the time of invocation of action?

Comment: vendettamit  - Code is above ... action functions will take in one int parameter :public void action1Func(int inParam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void execAction(int someInt, Action action)
{
    action();

    // or: action.Invoke();
}
```

You should be able to remove the whole lambda in the initialization as you already have a method with one int parameter right there:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _theActions = new Dictionary<theActions, Action<int>>
    {
        [theActions.action1] = action1Func
    };
}
```

The call with a specific parameter would look like:

```
int yourParameter = 12345;
execAction(42, () => (_theActions[theActions.action1]).Invoke(yourParameter));
```

Comment: Actually ... execAction needs to execute the Actions with a parameter passed in.  I apologize, for not being able to explain things. I'm not very smart.

Comment: Plus, I'll be storing a bunch of Actions, which I'll need to be randomly executing.  So, I want the execAction(1, whateveraction) logic working.  Note: the first parameter passed in, is for stuff in the function and NOT the one I need to pass into the action.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking. You need to be more specific.

Comment: I want to use the function execAction, which takes a separate int parameter and a action, which needs to be passed in with it's own parameter,  So ,,, like .. execAction(1, anAction(aIntParameter)).  In my case, the actions need to be stored in a dictionary.  I want to pass _theActions[theActions.action1] in with a parameter, that will get executed, in execAction().

Comment: So pass `yourParameterToPass` as a third parameter to `execAction`.

Comment: That seems, like a workaround.  Not, a bad one and I wouldn't make fun of anybody doing that.  But, seems like there's got to be a way, to pass the parameter in with the action. :(  Maybe, I've been on a wild goose chase.

Comment: You could construct a lambda of your action with a parameter, making it an action that can be called later...

Comment: @tobeypeters Edited the answer.

Comment: That looks good.  Thank you.  You've been so much help in here.  Well, everybody else too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop the dictionary and use this instead:

```
public void action1Func(int p1) //action 1 has one int parameter
{
}
public void action2Func() //let's consider action 2 takes no parameters
{
}
public void action3Func(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
}
// Order of parameters was changed to leverage implicit null parameters for convenience
// See invocations below
public void execAction(theActions action, 
                       int? inVar1 = null, int? inVar2 = null, int? inVar3 = null) 
{
    switch (action) // Based on action kind, invoke the right function.
    {               // The mapping is now coded in a switch statement 
                    // instead of a Dictionary declaration
        case theActions.action1: action1Func(inVar1.Value); break;
        case theActions.action2: action2Func(); break;
        case theActions.action3: action3Func(inVar1.Value, inVar2.Value, inVar3.Value); break;
    }
}
// Invocations
execAction(theActions.action1, 1);
execAction(theActions.action2);
execAction(theActions.action3, 1, 3, 5);
```

You can call methods with arbitrary number of parameters if you use the implicit parameter declaration correctly for execAction.

You can perform parameter validation (e.g. above you can check that inVar1.HasValue == true before invoking) otherwise the code will fail fast if you omit a parameter (Nullable.Value throws InvalidOperationException if HasValue is false).

If number of parameters grows and becomes unmanageable you can put them in a parameters bag class and validate their initialization via constructor.

You can get more safety (compile time checks) if you define these overloads:

```
public void execAction1(int p1)
    => execAction(theActions.action1, p1);
public void execAction2()
    => execAction(theActions.action2);
public void execAction3(int p1, int p2, int p3)
    => execAction(theActions.action3, p1, p2, p3);

// Invocations will be
execAction1(1);
execAction2();
execAction3(1, 3, 5);
```

but this last step kind of defeats the purpose. You can invoke the original methods instead :).

Comment: You can also declare a Dictionary<theActions,Delegate> and force a cast to Action as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099366/how-make-dictionary-with-lambda-functions-with-different-numbers-of-parameters). But bear in mind DynamicInvoke has serious performance implications.

Comment: Cosmin ... I know, how to do that.  I appreciate, the answer.  Code is spot on.  But, I want to do it like above.  If I don't have any parameters, The code above works.  I can just pass in the action & do action();  If anything, I want to fix it, for learning purposes.  Cause, my first thought was well you just add <int> to each Action.  That didn't work.

Comment: So, I tried the DynamicInvoke().  That worked if I called it "manually".  But, I need to pass the action into a function, as in the code above.  But, I did a little looking, DynamicInvoke() has too much of a performance hit, as you implied.  I just want to convert the code I posted to take Actions with parameters.